# SQLite: Can not insert data into table

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I want to insert this dictonary "all_movies" into a the table "movie_table".

The data is webscraped with asyncio and then gathered in original_movies.

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movie_table 
(actor_rank INTEGER, movie_name TEXT, year TEXT, genre TEXT, rating TEXT);"
```

I tried multiple ways and I have got following errors:

**1. Error:**

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. 
The current statement uses 5, and there are 65 supplied.
```

With this query (original_movie changed)

```
insertQuery = '''INSERT INTO 
movie_table (actor_rank, movie_name, year, genre, rating) VALUES (:actor_rank, :movie_name, :year, :genre, :rating)'''
            
cursor.executemany(insertQuery, original_movie)
connection.commit()
```

**2. Error:**

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. 
The current statement uses 5, and there are 1 supplied.
```

With this query (original_movie changed)

```
insertQuery = '''INSERT INTO 
movie_table (actor_rank, movie_name, year, genre, rating) VALUES (:actor_rank, :movie_name, :year, :genre, :rating)'''
            
cursor.executemany(insertQuery, [original_movie])
connection.commit()
```

**3. Error:**

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. 
The current statement uses 5, and there are 65 supplied.
```

With this query (VALUES changed and original_movies is now a list with tuples)

```
insertQuery = '''INSERT INTO 
movie_table (actor_rank, movie_name, year, genre, rating) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''
            
cursor.executemany(insertQuery, original_movie)
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, original_movie is a list of dictionaries. So you can do something like that

```
for movie in original_movie:
    insertQuery = '''INSERT INTO movie_table (actor_rank, movie_name, year, genre, rating) VALUES (:actor_rank, :movie_name, :year, :genre, :rating)'''
            
    cursor.execute(insertQuery, (**movie,))
    connection.commit()
```

Or you can rewrite get_actors_movies func to use executemany method

```
def get_actors_movies():
for ... in ...:
      movie_data = [ index,
                     movie.find('a', href=True).text.strip(),
                     movie.find('span').text.strip(),
                     movie_soup.find('span', class_=re.compile('ipc-chip__text')).text,
                     'TO-DO'
              ]
      all_movies.append(movie_data)
return all_movies

...

insertQuery = '''INSERT INTO movie_table (actor_rank, movie_name, year, genre, rating) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''
        
cursor.executemany(insertQuery, original_movie)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: I get a snytax error with `cursor.execute(insertQuery, (**movie,))`. With the second solution I get the error `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 65 supplied.`